# What is the function to the following graph?

Tags: graphing-functions

What is the function to the following graphs?
I am just looking for a rough estimate. It doesn't need to match the exact graph.
[image]

Comment: maybe $ \ x^ {-n }  \  $ could do the job?

Comment: Yeah that is close. But since it is only in the first quadrant, is there a way to express that in the function?

Comment: They can't be $x^{-n}$ because the two lower graphs cross each other and the top graph appears to have a minimum around $58$ - I'd quote colours if I were not colour-blind.

Comment: @user1738154 well, all we see is the first quadrant .Who knows what kind of strange things are happening on the other quadrants (:

Comment: Nothing is happening on the other quadrants. That is why I only posted the first quadrant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you think is happening to the right.  Clearly it goes to infinity for $x=0$ so there is a denominator of $x^n$.  If they each approach a constant, I would say each is $a+x^{-n}$.  The fact that the corner on the green one is sharper than the others would say it has a greater $n$.  I would collect some points from each graph, estimate the asymptote, and see what $n$ fits best.

If you think the rise of the red one toward the right is real, you could add a term $+bx$ for a rather small $b$.